# how to find the maximum and minimum index of an element in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, indexing

I have data set with thousands values as following in a vector:

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

The property of the data:

1)  The values are consecutive integers by starting from 1.

2) The number of each value is not always the same.

The aim:

Find the minimum and maximum index of each value in the vector.The expected result should be:

```
 minimum index: [0, 3,5,9,14,16]
 maximum index: [2, 4,8,13,15,20]
```

Could some one give me easy solution?
Thanks

Comment: Downvoted because poster wants entire solution and didn't do any work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cauchy: a map of pairs would be slower and more complex than it needs to be.  Dumping the results to stdout actually takes more lines than a simple solution:

```cxx
// assuming compiler doesn't support initialization lists for std::vector:
int ai[] = { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7 };
std::vector<int> values(ai, ai+(sizeof(ai)/sizeof(ai[0])));

std::vector<int> boundaries;
int prevValue = values[0] - 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
    if (prevValue != values[i]){
        boundaries.push_back(i);
        prevValue = values[i];
    }
}

// show lower boundaries
std::cout << "[" ;
for (size_t i = 0; i < boundaries.size(); i++){
    std::cout << " " << boundaries[i];
}
std::cout << "]" << std::endl;

// show upper boundaries
std::cout << "[" ;
for (size_t  i = 1; i < boundaries.size(); i++){
    std::cout << " " << boundaries[i] - 1;
}
std::cout << " " << values.size() - 1;
std::cout << " ]" << std::endl;
```

Note that we only need the lower boundary index *LB[i]* for each value array element *VA[n]* because the upper boundary *UB[i]* for *VA[n]* will always be *LB[i+1] - 1*, except for *UB[last]* which is by definition the max valid index for *VA*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the pseudo code for your problem:

1.Create a map of `map<int,pair<int,int>`. Key is value from vector and corresponding value for the key is start index and end index.

2.For each key in vector check if first value of pair is present or not.

```
 IF yes:
   then update the second value with current index.
  else 
   update the first value with current index.
```

3.Finally iterate over all the key value pair.

Additional advantages now you can access the start and end of any key directly.